# Getting the number of months between two dates sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns `id, last_name, date_hired`
I need to find out the number of months since date_hired and today. I can't figure out how to use the date_hired in `Months_Between` function. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT LAST_NAME AS Name, 
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(
         TO_DATE(DATE_HIRED,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
         TO_DATE('01-01-1995','MM-DD-YYYY')) "Months"
  FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

I have searched for this question but none of the other questions use data from another column.

Comment: What happens when you run that? What data type is `date_hired`? Also are you only looking for the number of whole months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DATE_HIRED` is `DATE` datatype, use

```
SELECT LAST_NAME AS Name, 
   MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE_HIRED, SYSDATE) "Months"
  FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

If it is `CHAR` datatype (or derived), use

```
SELECT LAST_NAME AS Name, 
   MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(DATE_HIRED,'MM-DD-YYYY'), SYSDATE) "Months"
  FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Format `'MM-DD-YYYY'` depends on stored date string format.

Comment: You might want to put `sysdate` as the first argument so you get a positive number back; and also possibly trunc the result to get the number of whole months? (Also you're specifying the date model in `to_date()`, so NLS settings don't matter here?)